# Creating A Function to Calculate the Skewness of a Given Vector

Tags: r, statistics

I am looking to create a function, in R, that calculates the skewness of a given vector based on the formula (in the image) below:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as an FYI the `e1071` package has a `skewness` function that deals with three types of functions. While none of the types are what you want you may want to have a look at the source code to see how its structured. It will help a lot in improving functions you write

Comment: Perfect! I love learning about new packages. Gonna start digging into it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function:

```
skew <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE){
  if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  n <- length(x)
  sum((x - mean(x))^3)/(n - 2)/var(x)^(3/2)
}
```